# What free software can batch process HDR images?

Tags: software, hdr, batch

I am looking for free software that is able to batch-process HDR images. I used a +2,-2 bracketing on my camera (so I have 3 pics taken for each position). I'm trying to create panoramic images, so I need the batch to always use the same recipe I defined.

Comment: See [What tools do you recommend for creating HDR images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/what-tools-do-you-recommend-for-creating-hdr-images) as a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) has a Batch Processor. The goal of it is to make stitching of multiple projects faster. It can be run from the GUI or using the command line. You do have to create several project files to do this. The advantage is that you can basically leave the projects unattended while they all process. It saves you the time if you have a slower computer or are doing a large amount of projects.

More info about the [Hugin Batch Processor can be found here](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Batch_Processor).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a GIMP script, such as [this one](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24500) (I think there are many others available, too, if you search around), and run GIMP in [batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).